# How to access the key value of a selected row in UiTableView using NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to delete a cell/row and in order to do that I need to pass the key value the row contains so that I can remove it from the NSMutableDictionary. I am new to xcode so please excuse me for asking such simple question. But your help will highly appreciated.

This is what I am using now.

```
 [self.userSelectedNamesAndMeaning removeObjectForKey:indexPath];
```

I need to replace indexPath with the key value of the NSMutableDictionary "userSelectedNamesAndMeaning"

Here is my `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"thirdViewControllerCell"];
    if (nil==cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"thirdViewControllerCell"];
    }
    // Give the name for the current row
    NSString *currentBoyName = [self.allSelectedNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [[cell textLabel] setText:currentBoyName];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Here is my tableView
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"thirdViewControllerCell"];
    if (nil==cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"thirdViewControllerCell"];
    }
    // Give the name for the current row
    NSString *currentBoyName = [self.allSelectedNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [[cell textLabel] setText:currentBoyName];
    return cell;
}

Comment: What's the connection to the `userSelectedNamesAndMeaning` dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here. I should have passed instead of indexPath as it is looking for the key at the row.

```
 [self.allSelectedNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
```

which is the "currentBoyName"